# How to add elements to req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, request, body-parser

I am trying to use MongoDB collections and relate one collection to another. I have one collection named "player" and one named "calendar", and I am trying to add player info to calendar events so only the player logged into the system can see their specific events.

I can see all the info of the event when I console log req.body:

```
{ start_date: '2019-02-09 00:00',
end_date: '2019-02-09 00:05',
text: 'New event',
id: '5c5a6bc5ea427e54cd4714d6',
'!nativeeditor_status': 'updated' }
```

The id you are seeing is the EVENT id. I want to add a field userID using passport (req.user.id) that way I can then search the collection and populate events of the logged in player.

My question is how to add fields to the req.body element? My calendar and player schemas are as follows:

**player.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    calendar: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'calendar'
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('player', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**calendar.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    start_date: {type: Date, required: true},
    end_date:   {type: Date, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'player', required: true}
});

const calendar = mongoose.model('calendar', schema);

module.exports = calendar;
```

Here is how I'm implementing the calendar in my route index.js:

```
    //schedule
    router.get('/calendar', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        req.body.user = req.user.id;
        var db = require('mongoskin').db("mongodb://tdipietro87:tdipietro87@tmcluster-shard-00-00-pbtwu.mongodb.net:27017,tmcluster-shard-00-01-pbtwu.mongodb.net:27017,tmcluster-shard-00-02-pbtwu.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=TMCluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true", { w: 0});
        db.bind('calendar');

        var Calendar = require('../models/calendar');

        Calendar.find({user: req.user.id}) // query by specific user
    .then(function (data) {
        // ...


            router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
            router.use(bodyParser.json());
            router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

            router.get('/init', function(req, res){
                db.calendar.insert({ 
                    text:"My test event A", 
                    start_date: new Date(2018,8,1),
                    end_date:   new Date(2018,8,5)
                });
                db.calendar.insert({ 
                    text:"My test event B", 
                    start_date: new Date(2018,8,19),
                    end_date:   new Date(2018,8,24)
                });
                db.calendar.insert({ 
                    text:"Morning event", 
                    start_date: new Date(2018,8,4,4,0),
                    end_date:   new Date(2018,8,4,14,0)
                });
                db.calendar.insert({ 
                    text:"One more test event", 
                    start_date: new Date(2018,8,3),
                    end_date:   new Date(2018,8,8),
                    color: "#DD8616"
                });

                res.send("Test events were added to the database")
            });


            router.get('/data', function(req, res){
                db.calendar.find().toArray(function(err, data){
                    //set id property for all records
                    console.log(err);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        data[i].id = data[i]._id;

                    //output response
                    res.send(data);
                });
            });


            router.post('/data', function(req, res){
                console.log(req.body);
                console.log(req.user.id);
                var data = req.body;
                var mode = data["!nativeeditor_status"];
                var sid = data.id;
                var tid = sid;

                delete data.id;
                delete data.gr_id;
                delete data["!nativeeditor_status"];


                function update_response(err, result){
                    if (err)
                        mode = "error";
                    else if (mode == "inserted")
                        tid = data._id;

                    res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                    res.send({action: mode, sid: sid, tid: tid});
                }

                if (mode == "updated")
                    db.calendar.updateById( sid, data, update_response);
                else if (mode == "inserted")
                    db.calendar.insert(data, update_response);
                else if (mode == "deleted")
                    db.calendar.removeById( sid, update_response);
                else
                    res.send("Not supported operation");
            });


        res.render('calendar', {
            name: req.user.name
        })
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very complicated to answer, but i want to give some clue

```
const newEvent = new Calendar({ //Calendar is your models name
      ....fill with another required field in models
      text : req.body.text,
      user : req.user.id //look again, how you decode incoming token request and declare them
});
```